# Sequelize groupwise maxium

Tags: mysql, node.js, grouping, sequelize.js, groupwise-maximum

I have tried to do groupwise maximum with sequelize, but could not find any solutions besides raw query.

For example I have an 1:m association. `symbols` table has many rows in `company_key_statistics` table. `company_key_statistics` has column `createdAt` which is timestamp indicating when row has been created. I need to join latest `symbols` with `company_key_statistics`, but I need only latest `company_key_statistics`. For example I need to get `ORCL` and `MSFT` symbols and only their latest `company_key_statistics`.

I wanted to know is it possible to do such things with sequelize built-in methods or only way is raw queries?

**UPDATE**

I had asked same [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170756/mysql-limit-within-join) question but for plain MySQL, maybe based on this question someone can answer how to deal with sequelize.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did the solution work ?

Comment: @Adiii, Thank you for help, but unfortunately, this is not what I wanted.

Comment: so i am here you can share what you want with some code logic

Answer (score 1):

In my option!, I think this will give you some help

```
             sql.findAll({
                        attributes: [
                            [sqldb.sequelize.fn('MAX', sqldb.sequelize.col('price')), "max"]
                        ],
                        group: [
                            "key"
                        ],
                        order: [
                            "key"
                        ],
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible in both ways

```
var models = require('./database/models'); //path to your models
var user = require('./database/models').user; //path to your user models

user.findAll(
    {group: 'age',

     order: [
    [models.sequelize.fn('max', models.sequelize.col('age')), 'DESC'],
    // will return max(`age`) DESC and will groupby age
  ]
    }
).then(function(result)
                   {
    res.json(result)
})
```

for more detail

[manipulating-the-dataset-with-limit-offset-order-and-group](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#manipulating-the-dataset-with-limit-offset-order-and-group)

[raw-queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#raw-queries)

[getting-started-with-sequelize-and-the-sequelize-cli](http://gregtrowbridge.com/getting-started-with-sequelize-and-the-sequelize-cli/)